# PowerShell script to get user information takes hours to run--any way to do it faster?

Tags: python, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft365

This PowerShell script to get a lot of user information from Microsoft 365 and write to csv works fine, but is taking a LONG time to run (like hours) for about 12k users. Is there any way to do this in a faster way? Is there an API I can call from Python that would do this faster?

```
# Get all users from AAD
$all = get-azureaduser -All $true

# Empty the output file we will use

$path = 'c:\blahblahpath\M365users.csv'
$path -replace ' ', '` '
Clear-Content -Path $path

# Loop through all users, get attributes and write to csv
$all | foreach-object {

$user = $_
$mbx = ""
$fwd = ""
$mbx = get-mailbox $user.userprincipalname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$fwd = $mbx.forwardingsmtpaddress
$extem = $mbx.externalemailaddress
$aliases = $mbx.emailaddresses

# Expanding only the Extension Attributes related to the user and converting the Dictionary to Custom Object
#   so that keys can be accessed through the dot (.) operator
$Extension_Attributes = New-Object Psobject -Property $user.ExtensionProperty 

# Combining the required attributes from the user object and extension_attributes to A single object
$u_properties = [pscustomobject] @{
"UserPrincipalName" = $user.UserPrincipalName
"GivenName" = $user.GivenName
"Surname" = $user.Surname
"M3-DisplayName" = $user.DisplayName
"JobTitle" = $user.JobTitle
"Department" = $user.Department
"CompanyName" = $user.CompanyName
"M3-Mail" = $user.mail
"M3-OtherMails" = $user.OtherMails[0]
"ForwardingSmtpAddress" = $fwd
"ExternalEmailAddress" = $extem
"Aliases" = $aliases
"DeliverToMailboxAndForward" = $keepinmbx
"TelephoneNumber" = $user.TelephoneNumber
"PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName" = $user.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
"PreferredLanguage" = $user.PreferredLanguage
"MailNickName" = $user.MailNickName 
"StreetAddress" = $user.StreetAddress
"City" = $user.City
"State" = $user.State
"PostalCode" = $user.PostalCode
"Country" = $user.Country
"UsageLocation" = $user.UsageLocation
"Mobile" = $user.Mobile 
"UserType" = $user.UserType
"AccountEnabled" = $user.AccountEnabled
"LastLogon" = $user.LastLogon
"BlockCredential" = $user.BlockCredential
"AssignedLicenses" = $user.AssignedLicenses
"Created" = $Extension_Attributes.createdDateTime 
"MemberNumber" = $Extension_Attributes.EmployeeID
"TokenExp" = $user.RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime
"OLDMemNumExt" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_60a1274a0a9d4344bd172d81b06d0f50_MemberNumber
"Source" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_06f8dc5952b048a1879af4e793844173_Source
"M3-MemType" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_MemType
"M3-Status" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_Status
"EmailTeams" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_EmailTeams
"M3-EmailCC" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_EmailCC
"M3-EmailPri" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_EmailPri
"Cert" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_Cert
"M3-ExpDate" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_ExpDate
"WGTitle" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_WGTitle
"ChapTitle" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_ChapTitle
"OtherTitle" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_LdrTitle
"Othercodes" = $extension_Attributes.extension_11b052b5eb8f4c77973a06876d25a6a4_Othercodes
"ChapCodes" = $extension_Attributes.extension_11b052b5eb8f4c77973a06876d25a6a4_ChapCodes
"WGcodes" = $extension_Attributes.extension_11b052b5eb8f4c77973a06876d25a6a4_WGcodes
"Allcodes" = $extension_Attributes. extension_a14f14664c8e457a856d24680b31c9d4_AllCodes
"Cmems" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_4adef2735ffb4a9dafc9a85188ca512d_Cmems
"M3-isnet" = $Extension_Attributes.extension_01816427922e40c9b55cf4364bc171ce_IsNet
"SipProxyAddress" = $user.SipProxyAddress
}

# check
#write-host "got $u_properties"

$u_properties | Export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append

}#
```

I timed the `$all = get-azureaduser -All $true` at about 20 seconds, so obviously the time is in the loop--maybe the 'get-mailbox...' is slow?

I'm fairly novice at PowerShell so I can't think of a lot of other ways to try doing this.

Comment: Have you tried just querying all mailboxes at once, instead of going through the AAD identity lookup 12k times? `Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit Users -ResultSize Unlimited`

Comment: I dont see something terribly wrong with your code except for the last `Export-Csv -Append`. That will slow your script immensely, you need to put it as a last statement in your pipeline

Comment: I think you can better do 2 calls. 1) `get-azureaduser -All $true`, and 2) `Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit Users`  (see: [Get-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)),   and then do some scripting to combine those 2 lists. (I'm fairly novice at PowerShell too, so ...)

Comment: I agree that appending to the CSV is slow.  I recommend opening a [System.IO]:: StreamReader(filename).  Then write the CSV as you get data.  Using One PS command line can use lots of memory.  Monitor in Task Manage the memory usage.  If you write as you go along (and not appending) the memory usage will go down.  One statement doesn't run more efficiently than multiple statements.

Comment: @Luuk he does `-all $true` already

Answer (score 1):

I believe with simply putting `Export-Csv` as the last statement of your pipeline your script time will improve greatly. Appending to a Csv means that in each loop iteration `Export-Csv` has to open the [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0), seek until the EOF, append the new line (a single object) and close the stream. This is a really expensive thing to do 12k times. Instead, if you put it as the last statement, no `-Append` is needed and the `FileStream` is kept opened until no more output is coming from your `ForEach-Object`.

```bash
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | ForEach-Object {
    # same logic here
} | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation # here is the last statement, no append needed.
```

To put it into perspective how bad is `-Append` inside a loop, you can run the following test:

```bash
$test = @{
    'With Append' = {
        $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
        0..12000 | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                foo = 'bar'
            } | Export-Csv $tmp.FullName -Append
        }
        $tmp | Remove-Item
    }
    'Pipeline Processing' = {
        $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
        0..12000 | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                foo = 'bar'
            }
        } | Export-Csv $tmp.FullName
        $tmp | Remove-Item
    }
}

$test.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Test = $_.Key
        Time = (Measure-Command { & $_.Value }).TotalMilliseconds
    }
}
```